# Regarding adding new Google Assistant Custom actions for devices authorization failure

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am a developer working with Google Assistant SDK for building and testing Custom actions for devices.

When working with Google Assistant custom actions CLI i am facing below error.

**Error Message in browser **:
Access blocked: Assistant CLI’s request is invalid
You can’t sign in because Assistant CLI sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of Assistant CLI, see error details.
Error 400: invalid_request

[image]

When working with Google Assistant custom actions i followed Google Assistant guideline.

I followed below steps.

1. Google Assistant SDK for building and testing Custom actions, I created new project under https://console.actions.google.com/project/test16-xyz/overview
2. 

under https://console.actions.google.com/project/test16-xyz/overview
Quick setup (on how your action will be invoked)

3. Create Device registration under develop tab https://console.actions.google.com/project/test16-xyz/deviceregistration/
4. I have enabled Google Assistant API's for this project under https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/
5. I have downloaded client_secret.json from this project under https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/
6. Downloaded the gactions cli into same folder as downloaded client_secret.json file
   https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/actions-sdk/gactions-cli#downloads
7. I have created manually custom actions.json in the same folder as client_secret.json
8. Below command executed to update actions to Google my project account(example : test16-xyz).

#gactions.exe update --action_package actions.json --project test16-xyz
Gactions needs access to your Google account. Please copy & paste the URL below into a web browser and follow the instructions there. Then copy and paste the authorization code from the browser back here.
Visit this URL:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=237807841406-o6vu1tjkq8oqjub8jilj6vuc396e2d0c.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Factions.builder&state=state
Enter authorization code:

I did copy & paste the above URL into a web browser, then got  Error 400: invalid_request (sample message as below)

**Error Message in browser **:
Access blocked: Assistant CLI’s request is invalid
You can’t sign in because Assistant CLI sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of Assistant CLI, see error details.
Error 400: invalid_request

I am facing the above said issue. Any support on this issue would be of great help ?